# Request in PhpUnit using Laravel 5.1

Tags: unit-testing, laravel-5.1

I'm testing my Rest APIs.

I want to pass a parameter to my request.

This is in my controller, I have:

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
     $abuse = Abuse::where('bombId', $request->input('bombId'))->get();
}
```

Thing is with PhpUnit, I can never simulate the bombId parameter...

Here is my code:

```
 $data['bombId'] = 25; // I also tried $bombId = 25;
 $this->get('api/v1/abuse', $data])
           ->seeJson(['total' => 11]);
 $this->assertResponseStatus(200);
```

EDIT:

When I use:

```
$this->call('GET','api/v1/abuse', $credentials);
```

Param is passed, but I can't use anymore SeeJson method :(

Any Idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my answer with [Jeffrey Way:](https://gist.github.com/JeffreyWay/5623836)

```
    $response = $this->call('GET', 'api/v1/abuse', $credentials);
    $data = $this->parseJson($response);
    $this->assertIsJson($data);
    $this->assertEquals(11, $data->total);
```